# How to send push notification in flutter based on expiry date which is there in firestore database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

flutter firebase firestore cloud functions

eg. push notification should come 15 days before expiry date.

if(exp_date - Date.now() == 15){
push notification}

Comment: Hello, what did you already try? Do you have any code to share? I would kindly suggest that you check out this help page: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: did you find something? Looking for the same